# How to detect that federated prometheus stopped delivering metrics?

Tags: federation, prometheus

I have two "slave" prometheus severs, one in each of my kubernetes clusters. I have one centralised prometheus for [federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/federation/) and [alerting](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/overview/).

Sometimes, it happens that a "slave" stops delivering metrics. How to detect it? How to create an alert that catches such a situation.

Unfortunately, prometheus always sees its federated peers as UP. No matter what.

Answer (score -1):

We need a bit more information here. If up is 1 then everything is okay. The real question is why you're getting a successful scrape with no data. Have you tried debugging that?

I'd also suggest alerting as deep in the stack as you can, see https://www.robustperception.io/federation-what-is-it-good-for/